# How to intercept I/O db operations in Hibernate?

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

Could I add listener to Hibernate which would be triggered on each access to sql db?

I want to execute Hibernate queries in MyThread and in this listeners I'm going to check: Thread.currentTread() instanceof MyThread.

The thread checking should be invoked before I/O operation. UnexpectedThreadException should be triggered if current thread isn't instance of MyThread.

I tried to use org.hibernate.interceptor, but it seems there is no method that is called before data reading from db.

Comment: org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor. See its usage

Comment: onPrepareStatement?
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/EmptyInterceptor.html#onPrepareStatement-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 0):

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.addEventListeners(new BaseSessionEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void jdbcExecuteStatementStart() {
        DbTaskThread.requireDbTaskThread();
        super.jdbcExecuteStatementStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void jdbcConnectionReleaseStart() {
        DbTaskThread.requireDbTaskThread();
        super.jdbcConnectionReleaseStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void jdbcConnectionAcquisitionStart() {
        DbTaskThread.requireDbTaskThread();
        super.jdbcConnectionAcquisitionStart();
    }
});
```